# java script function works only once

Tags: javascript, function, css-transforms

this is the function used in order to rotate the `p` element:

```js
<script>
function ani() {

  var z = document.getElementById("rotate");
  z.style.webkitTransition = "1.2s";
  z.style.transition = "1.2s" ;
  z.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.OTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
  }
</script>
```

here is the whole code, including html and javascript:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>animation</title>
        <meta chartset="utf-8">

        <script>
        function ani() {
            var z = document.getElementById("rotate");
            z.style.webkitTransition = "1.2s";
            z.style.transition = "1.2s" ;
            z.style.transform = "rotateY(360deg)";
            z.style.webkitTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
            z.style.OTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
            z.style.MozTransform = "rotateY(360deg)";
        }
        </script>
    </head>

    <body>
        <div>
            <p onmouseover="ani()" id="rotate" style="background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5); text-align: center; color: #fff;">Great this is rotating!</p>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what is the question?

Comment: Once you set the style, setting the style to the same thing again won't cause any further change.

Comment: Put the transition in a class. Add the class on mouseover, remove it on mouseout. Pretty easy using the [*classList* API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList). Note that you need to wait for the animation to complete before removing it, so there's a bit more smarts than that required to get a decent effect.

Answer (score 3):

You should learn to make .css files and import them instead of styling everything in HTML and JavaScript. This is just plain good practice.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-US">
    <head>
        <title>animation</title>
        <meta chartset="utf-8"/>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css"/>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="rotate">Great this is rotating!</p>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (style.css):

```
#rotate {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    text-align: center;
    color: #fff;
}

#rotate:hover {
    -webkit-transition: 1.2s all;
    transition: 1.2s all;
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -moz-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    -o-transform: rotateY(360deg);
    transform: rotateY(360deg);
}
```

JavaScript:

```
// Nothing! Fantastic!
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all you comments and answers, you enlighten me.
here it's what i do , use other function that resets the style and use a delay in order to wait the animation complete as @RobG wrote.

I make use of setInterval() function for setting the delay , and clearInterval()for stoping the continuos execution.

I apologize for my english , i'm out of practice.

```js
   
var z;

function ani(){
 
  z=document.getElementById("rotate");
  z.style.webkitTransition="all 1.2s";
  z.style.transition="all 1.2s" ;
  z.style.transform="rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.webkitTransform="rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.OTransform="rotateY(360deg)";
  z.style.MozTransform="rotateY(360deg)";
  
  z.addEventListener("webkitTransitionEnd", unani);
  z.addEventListener("transitionend", unani);

}

function unani(){


  z.style.webkitTransition="";
  z.style.transition="" ;
  z.style.transform="";
  z.style.webkitTransform="";
  z.style.OTransform="";
  z.style.MozTransform="";
 

}
```

Comment: Rather than using a timer, you should use the `transitionend` event.

Comment: @torazaburo rather than using JavaScript he should be using CSS

Comment: thanks @torazaburo answer modified by using a transitioned event.

Comment: Using `transitionEnd` is good, but you really need to switch to using classes for the CSS. Also, AFAIK you no longer need the `webkitTransitionEnd` alternative.